# Black box appearing in top right corner at some interval and then disappers

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, intel-graphics, screen, hp

i am using ubuntu 20.04.01. from few days i am seeing a black box appearing for some time and then disappears completly. here is the screenshot[image: this image] don't know what that is or how can i get rid of this..?

Comment: is that the notification area? Please check it with running `notify-send test` from terminal or Alt+f2 (Run command). Might be some outdated gnome extension?

Comment: @pLumo i ran this command. but nothing shows up neither in terminal or on display..

Comment: Does this problem persist reboot?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes it does.

Comment: What desktop environment is this? If Gnome Shell, then first disable extensions one by one until the problem disappears.

Comment: @vanadium i have installed only one extension that is hide top bar. is it causing any issue? i disabled it and it is still causing that issue.